# split date(form: YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS) column to two part

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have edited the problem to make it clear what I want to acieve.

This is data I get :

```
                  Date   open   high  close    low   volume  price_change
0  2015-03-25 13:55:00  15.37  15.38  15.35  15.34  1121.00         -0.02
1  2015-03-25 14:00:00  15.36  15.38  15.36  15.34   595.00          0.00
2  2015-03-25 14:05:00  15.36  15.38  15.36  15.35  1369.01          0.00
3  2015-03-25 14:10:00  15.36  15.40  15.40  15.36  3215.55          0.04
4  2015-03-25 14:15:00  15.40  15.45  15.39  15.39  1563.45         -0.01
```

I want to split the date column into two columns, one is this form "2015-03-25" and one is "13:55:00".

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  Do you want to convert strings to timestamps?  Are you converting 2001 Dates to 1990 Dates?  The AAPL values are diff as well.  Do you have datetimes already and just want to display zero minutes?

Comment: Please also show `df.info()`

Comment: it's possible that if your index is already a datetmeindex then the display is not showing the time as a convenience because it was created without a time component

Comment: The AAPL value is not important. What I want to do is to convert  2001-12-31  to 1990-01-02 00:00:00+00:00 .  To put 00:00:00+00:00 into the date.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest the following ... the key bit of code is in the last two lines ... the rest of the code was to recreate your DataFrame ...

```
# load your data
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for python 3
data = """     Date,   open,   high,  close,    low,   volume,  price_change
2015-03-25 13:55:00,  15.37,  15.38,  15.35,  15.34,  1121.00,         -0.02
2015-03-25 14:00:00,  15.36,  15.38,  15.36,  15.34,  595.00,           0.00
2015-03-25 14:05:00,  15.36,  15.38,  15.36,  15.35,  1369.01,          0.00
2015-03-25 14:10:00,  15.36,  15.40,  15.40,  15.36,  3215.55,          0.04
2015-03-25 14:15:00,  15.40,  15.45,  15.39,  15.39,  1563.45,         -0.01"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, index_col=None, skipinitialspace=True)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# now let's create the date and time columns you want
df['date_only'] = [x.date() for x in df['Date']]
df['time_only'] = [x.time() for x in df['Date']]
```

The output this gives me is as follows ...

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                 Date   open   high  close    low   volume  price_change  \
0 2015-03-25 13:55:00  15.37  15.38  15.35  15.34  1121.00         -0.02   
1 2015-03-25 14:00:00  15.36  15.38  15.36  15.34   595.00          0.00   
2 2015-03-25 14:05:00  15.36  15.38  15.36  15.35  1369.01          0.00   
3 2015-03-25 14:10:00  15.36  15.40  15.40  15.36  3215.55          0.04   
4 2015-03-25 14:15:00  15.40  15.45  15.39  15.39  1563.45         -0.01   

    date_only time_only  
0  2015-03-25  13:55:00  
1  2015-03-25  14:00:00  
2  2015-03-25  14:05:00  
3  2015-03-25  14:10:00  
4  2015-03-25  14:15:00
```

It is worth noting the different types of data this creates.

```
In [62]: type(df.date_only[0])
Out[62]: datetime.date

In [63]: type(df.time_only[0])
Out[63]: datetime.time

In [64]: type(df.Date[0])
Out[64]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [65]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Date            5 non-null datetime64[ns]
open            5 non-null float64
high            5 non-null float64
close           5 non-null float64
low             5 non-null float64
volume          5 non-null float64
price_change    5 non-null float64
date_only       5 non-null object
time_only       5 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 400.0+ bytes
```

All of the above aside, you might be able to achieve what you want with the new .dt accessor attribute for a Series of datetime64[ns] objects (which the Date column above is). This was introduced in pandas 0.15.0. It allows you to do things like `df.Date.dt.year` to get the year from the datetime64[ns] object. Also month, day, hour, minute, second, etc., etc.